# Заменить в документе .doc теги на курсив

Tags: ms-word

Есть документ .doc, в котором расставлено много тегов `<i></i>` (для выкладки в вебе). Можно ли как-то автоматизированно, с помощью какой-нибудь замены, сделать текст внутри этих тегов курсивным и удалить теги?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, можно `doc` файл сохранить сначала как `html`, потом опять открыть в ворде как `web` версию и перевести в нормальную версию.

Обязательно в теле документа должен быть тег `<html>`, иначе Word принимает документ как обычный текст.

Comment: То есть, добавить в файл обрамляющие html-теги `html, body, head`, а потом попробовать по предложенной схеме?

Comment: @Heidel да я вот сейчас сам пробую, как правильней. По моему так: сохраняем doc файл как html файл. В нем <li> теги преобразуются в &lt;li&gt; и &lt;/li&gt;. Открываем html файл в редакторе любом, вырезаем эти теги. Файл заново открываем в ворде.

Comment: Так а текст внутри тегов станет курсивным?

Comment: @Heidel ам точно, тогда `&lt;li&gt;` надо не вырезать, а заменить на реальные теги `<li>` и `</li>`

Comment: Угу, угу буду вечером пробовать, отпишусь о результатах.

Answer (score 1):

Могу посоветовать вариант с LibreOffice:

1) открываем файл;
 2) жмем CTRL+H - найти и заменить;
 3) в строке "найти" вставляем: `<i>([\w\s]*)</i>`;
 4) в строке заменить - `$1`;
 5) в дополнительных параметрах ставим галочку "регулярные выражения";
 6) устанавливаем курсор в поле "заменить" и нажимаем кнопку "формат", ставим - курсив;
 7) "заменить" или "заменить все";
 8) ...
 9) PROFIT!

Возможно, в ms word есть что-то похожее, но в либре - точно работает.

Comment: В WORD`е - найти и заменить, поставить галочку "подстановочные знаки".
Найти : \<i\>(*)\</i\>
заменить на : ^&
поставить курсор в поле заменить и выбрать "формат - шрифт - курсив"
заменить все
после этого останется только заменить теги <i> и </i> на пробелы.

Comment: @Magos большое спасибо за вариант, сейчас пока никак не успеваю попробовать, но скоро займусь.